# Bootstrap align items in column

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I got the following problem:

Picture 1 shows the prototype:
[image]

Im using Bootstrap 5 as css framework. I thought i can handle it through the built in columns, but i dont find any solution and struggling hard right now.

Picture 2 shows my solution:
[image]

I tried flexbox but couldnt find any solution.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-1">
 <div class="row">
  <img src="https://place-hold.it/90" class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 facts-img">
  <h3 class="facts-header col-lg-2 col-md-12">
   Licht
  </h3>
  <p class="facts-p col-lg-6 col-md-12 facts-text">
   Das zentrale Element in unserem Leben. Es weckt Emotionen, beeinflusst unser
   Wohlbefinden und füllt unsere Energiespeicher auf. Durch das Licht nehmen wir die
   unterschiedlichen Farben wahr. Licht schafft Ambiente.
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure is not correct. You need a `row` to enclose the immediate `col`'s and then a new `row` for the next `col`. Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <img src="https://place-hold.it/90" class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 facts-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <h3 class="facts-header col-lg-2 col-md-12">
            Licht
          </h3>
          <p class="facts-p col-lg-6 col-md-12 facts-text">
            Das zentrale Element in unserem Leben. Es weckt Emotionen, beeinflusst unser Wohlbefinden und füllt unsere Energiespeicher auf. Durch das Licht nehmen wir die unterschiedlichen Farben wahr. Licht schafft Ambiente.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <img src="https://place-hold.it/90" class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 facts-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <h3 class="facts-header col-lg-2 col-md-12">
            Licht
          </h3>
          <p class="facts-p col-lg-6 col-md-12 facts-text">
            Das zentrale Element in unserem Leben. Es weckt Emotionen, beeinflusst unser Wohlbefinden und füllt unsere Energiespeicher auf. Durch das Licht nehmen wir die unterschiedlichen Farben wahr. Licht schafft Ambiente.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thx for the advice - im nearly there. Now the image on the start of each column should be centered, you got an advice for that?

Comment: No problem. Read the documentation well, it has almost everything you'd ever need.

Comment: Ye i need to look more into the documentation. You got any tutorial suggestion? :) 
Good BS5 tuts are rare atm.

Comment: Honestly I do not know. I just learned/am learning from the documentation itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give eagle eye view.
Use classes in following hierarchy

```
.Container 
   . row //main row
      .col //block for Licht  
        .row // wrapper for Licht
          .col // column for round object
          .col // column for text element
             .row // for heading Licht
             .row // for description 

      .col // column for Design 
        .row // wrapper for Design
          .col // column for round object
          .col // column for text element
             .row // for heading Design
             .row // for description
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with media object

**Example 1**

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="flex-shrink-0">
   <img src="https://www.pavilionweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/man-300x300.png" class="mr-3"  width="150" alt="...">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow-1 ms-3">
  <h5 class="mt-0">Media heading</h5>
   <p>
   This is some content from a media component. You can replace this with any content and adjust it as needed.
   </p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example 2**

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <img src="https://www.pavilionweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/man-300x300.png" class="mr-3 img-fluid"  alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <h3 class="facts-header col-lg-2 col-md-12">
            heading
          </h3>
          <p class="facts-p col-lg-6 col-md-12 facts-text">
           This is some content from a media component. You can replace this with any content and adjust it as needed.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `flex` for this

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row p-4 w-100">
 <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
  <div class="p-2">
   <img src="https://place-hold.it/90" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 facts-img rounded-circle">
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column ">
  <h3 class="facts-header col-lg-2 col-md-12">
   Licht
  </h3>
  <p class="facts-p col-lg-8 col-md-12 facts-text">
   Das zentrale Element in unserem Leben. Es weckt Emotionen, beeinflusst unser
   Wohlbefinden und füllt unsere Energiespeicher auf. Durch das Licht nehmen wir die
   unterschiedlichen Farben wahr. Licht schafft Ambiente.
  </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
  <div class="p-2">
   <img src="https://place-hold.it/90" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 facts-img rounded-circle">
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column ">
  <h3 class="facts-header col-lg-2 col-md-12">
   Licht
  </h3>
  <p class="facts-p col-lg-8 col-md-12 facts-text">
   Das zentrale Element in unserem Leben. Es weckt Emotionen, beeinflusst unser
   Wohlbefinden und füllt unsere Energiespeicher auf. Durch das Licht nehmen wir die
   unterschiedlichen Farben wahr. Licht schafft Ambiente.
  </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```